# Data structures with cyclic dependencies in haskell

Tags: haskell, cyclic-reference

I'm trying to implement simple parser in haskell using `parsec` library (for learning purposes). So I wrote bunch of data structutes and related functions like this:

```
data SourceElement 
    = StatementSourceElement Statement
    | FunctionSourceElement FunctionName FunctionBody

data Statement 
    = IfStatement Expr Statement Statement
    | WhileStatement Expr Statement

data FunctionBody = FunctionBody [SourceElement]

parseSourceElement :: Parser SourceElement
parseSourceElement = ...

parseFunctionBody :: Parser FunctionBody
parseFunctionBody = ...
```

It works fine. Now I want to split this stuff into two modules to separate `FunctionBody` and `Statement` data structures (because of readability issues). But I can't! The reason is cyclic dependency between `SourceElement` and `FunctionBody`.

So, is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Luqui's answer is good for the general case of removing cycles in data structures, but in your case I'd look at re-designing you syntax tree. In OO languages it is sometimes common to represent syntax with a general tree structure (like your SourceElement) and use tags (like your Statement enum) to label it, but in functional language with algebraic types like Haskell you can represent trees directly.

Comment: stephen tetley - General tree structure is a nice idea, but unfortunately it means that I can create (by accident) invalid syntax tree (if i correctly understand the idea). In my initial tree implementation any constructed tree is valid syntax tree for parsed language.

Comment: @sergeyz, I think you have misunderstood @stephentetley. I believe he was suggesting `data Statement = IfStatement Expr Statement Statement | WhileStatement Expr Statement`, etc. which actually makes sure that you can only create valid trees moreso than this representation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The typical way I break dependency cycles is by parameterizing something out.  In this case, your `Function` module might do function parsers for your language, but expressed in such a way that it can do so no matter what the rest of the language is like.  Thus:

```
module Function where 

data FunctionBody e = FunctionBody [e]

parseFunctionBody :: Parser e -> Parser (FunctionBody e)
```

And

```
module AST where

data SourceElement
    = StatementSourceElement Statement
    | FunctionSourceElement FunctionName (FunctionBody SourceElement)
```

Thus the mutual recursion is abstracted into a simple recursion + parameterization.  I think parameterization is at least as important as separating different things into different files, so it's kind of nice (and kind of annoying) that one forces the other.

Comment: I agree about the importance of parameterization, but it should be meaningful and thought-out, not ad-hoc.

Comment: I am only partially in agreement with you.  I think all code "should be meaningful and thought-out", and the choice of parameterization no more or less so.  Gotta try things out to know what getting it right looks like.  I would rather use an imperfectly parameterized module than one that is coupled to its context -- at least in the former case there is hope for someone who has another use in mind, even if it is some work away.  In the latter case you are screwed.

Comment: @luqui, I have parametrized my [original](https://github.com/zaretskysa/Jazzist/blob/develop/src/Parsing/Ast.hs) data structures and now I have some new modules: [Statement](https://github.com/zaretskysa/Jazzist/blob/decomposition/src/Parsing/Statement.hs), [Expression](https://github.com/zaretskysa/Jazzist/blob/decomposition/src/Parsing/Expression.hs). The bad thing is that it looks kind of messy.

Comment: @sergeyz, Yeah, that does look kind of messy.  It's too bad we have to make that trade-off in current Haskell -- for a long time I've wanted Coq-style "sections" that make highly parametric things more palatable.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell actually allows recursive modules, and GHC supports them (with a minor inconvenience of writing `.hs-boot` files). See [How to compile mutually recursive modules](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/separate_compilation.html#how-to-compile-mutually-recursive-modules).

I don't see anything wrong with using this feature here.

Comment: I don't think `.hs-boot` is that minor an inconvenience. The amount of inconvenience has caused me, at least, to switch to another strategy each time I have attempted it.  Perhaps it's my idealism -- I feel like .hs-boot files should be easy to automatically generate, so I feel frustrated when I have to write them myself.

Comment: You may find [#1409](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1409) an interesting read.